# C# WPF XML-Deserialization, Exception when XML-Doc is wrong

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

i'am deserializing a XML-File and want to check before if it's possible to deserialize it. 
I'am already checking if the file which i want to deserialize exists. But i also want to throw a MessageBox when the XML-Structure looks something like this:

```
<groups>
  <group id="group_cInterface">
    <device id="Server" />
    <device id="cInterface"
  </group>
</groups>
```

in the 4. Line there is /> missing, so the XML can not be deserialized. In this case i want a MessageBox which shows for example: "XML-File is wrong"

But how can i realize it?

Thanks!

EDIT: Code i use for XML Deserialization

```
                    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(test));
                    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(item);
                    object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    test XmlData = (test)obj;
                    reader.Close();
```

Comment: Try to deserialize - catch exception - show box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
try
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml("FILE_PATH");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```